# QT How to draw 500000 lines?

Tags: qt, memory, graphics, view

I need to draw a lot of (about 500000) little lines in some area like QGraphicsView.
I tried to use QPainterPath and QGraphicsScene, but adding 500000 lines to QPainterPath with lineTo() takes more than 500 mb of memory and my app is killed by my kernel.

Is there a way I can draw such amount of lines in QT?

Comment: How m,any of these lines are visible at any given time?

Comment: How many of them can any human viewer actually make sense of at any one time? I think that might be what @Jen was getting at. Can you determine a "most important" subset of them, maybe draw more as the user requests more detail in specific areas? Or draw them at at a limited rate, layering more up the longer they're in view?

Comment: Yes. If all are visible on a typical screen at the same time, they would average about 2 pixels each...

Comment: @shambulator @Jen I can unite many of this lines and get about 1000-2000 lines. I think I`ll do it later, but for know drawing about 992000 lines on QImage with QPainter works great and takes about 2-3 seconds on my old notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QGraphicsLineItem`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicslineitem.html)  probably has lower overhead than `QPainterPath`. But adding half of a million of them will negate the gain.

Assuming that you are treating all the lines as one item since you are adding lines to a `QPainterPath`, creating a custom `QGraphicsItem` and `paint()` the lines yourself will be the fastest way. It will also avoid all the memory burden of managing path and line structures.